# Why can't I assign hardware and guest os profiles to servers in the new SCVMM 2012 Service Templates?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, system-center, scvmm

Trying to learn SCVMM 2012, but I'm confused about how Guest OS and Hardware Profiles work with the new 2012 Service Templates.

I create a Hardware Profile and a Guest OS Profile. Then I open the Create VM Template wizard. In this wizard I can assign the Hardware and Guest OS profiles I created under the Configure Hardware and Configure Operating System steps in the wizard.

If I open the new Service Template wizard, select a Single Tier Server (for example), open the Service Template Designer and go to the properties of the server I find under Hardware Configuration and OS Configuration I cannot assign my Hardware and Guest OS profiles to the server.

Why is this? It seems like extra work to have not be able to assign these profiles to servers in a service template. Is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is as simple as creating a VM template, creating a service template, then when in the design view of the service template you can drag VM templates to servers. Obviously this is pretty basic stuff, but I had a hell of a time trying to figure this out googling. Also, Gen 2 VM templates aren't supported in Service Templates so they won't show up in design view.